# Trying to fill fragmentlist from activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to fill my *ListFagment* from an activity. As a result I get a `Content view not yet created` error. I found a few answers here and I tried to use `onActivityCreated()` but it did not help. Please help me to debug the problem.

My activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    fragment1 frag1;
    FrameLayout container;

    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frag1 = new fragment1();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, frag1)
        .commit();
        ListView list = frag1.getListView();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My fragment class

```
public class fragment1 extends ListFragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

My Log stack trace. This line return error `ListView list = frag1.getListView();`

```
`E/AndroidRuntime(431): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentlisttest/com.example.fragmentlisttest.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
ListView list = getListView();
```

Should be in `onActivityCreated` in Fragment instead of

```
ListView list = frag1.getListView();
```

in `MainActivity`. You need to wait till the fragment is attached to the activity

In `onActivityCreated` in `ListFragment`

```
ListView list = getListView();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also move the below

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
    "Blackberry" };
```

in `ListFragment` before `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that the activity is not yet created you have to run your code in OnActivityCreated not OnCreate